# java- Unable to set value in database table to reflect changes

Tags: java, java-7

I have simple web page that I can click on a drop down menu and choose a version of a document I like.Each version of a document has it's own file status represented by **Active (1)** or **Obsolete(2)**.

So if I change to any version of the document, then I will able to view the details of that document.And next to the document there's an Edit button which will display depending on the file status of the version.

Only one file can be Active at one time. So if there's two version,version A and version B where A is active, then B has to be obsolete.If I change to view version B(via drop down) then the Edit button should not displayed.

In my db, I have a column called `fstatus` represented by int. When it retrieves the document version, it checks that column value. If it's 1 then show the Edit button,otherwise it doesn't show the button.

My problem is when I change to an inactive version,I wish to set the value to a different value than 1 so it automatically removes the button. I can't seem to get it to work though so I need to know what am I doing wrong.

**Fmedia.java**: There's a getter and setter that retrieves and set value to the column in table

```
 public int getFstatus() {
        return fstatus;
    }

    public void setFstatus(int fstatus) {
        this.fstatus = fstatus;
    }
```

**File.java**:

```
    public Node get_folder(long fileID) {
     //this line is not that important
   List resList1 = nodeFacade.list_parent(fileID, LinkType.VER_LINKS);

       // This retrieves version document that are inactive
       if(resList1.size()==1){
          // grabs the unique fileID so it knows which row in the table to update the column status
          Fmedia fmedia = new Fmedia(fileID);
          //set the status column to 2 (initially it's 1)
          fmedia.setFstatus(2);
          // by changing the value to 2 before retrieving the record,it should  be able to retrieve the record now and not display the button.
          // returns the records of that inactive version.
          return (Node) resList1.get(0);
        }


    }
```

I suspect the issue lies in the line `fmedia.setFstatus(2);` because I actually needed to update the record from 1 to 2 and it's an existing record in the table.
Also, I ran a debug and it's able to retrieve the correct fileID but somehow it's not able to update the status column,meaning it's still 1 which is not what I want.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: so you are creating a new instance of "Fmedia" inside File.java and what you do with it after? -- don't you have to do something like ```resList.get(0).replaceFmedia(fmedia);```?

Comment: @BookOfZeus I created the instance in the File.java then I retrieve the fileID, then I want to set the particular column to value 2 for example.

Comment: ```new Fmedia(fileID);``` please post the code of the constructor

Comment: @BookOfZeus My bad, the `return` code is supposed to be inside of the IF loop

Comment: I edited my post, the fileID is supposed to be a parameter passing in the function.

Comment: why don't you pass "Fmedia fmedia" instead of the "long fileId" to this method instead.

Comment: The fileID parameter is being passed to `list_parent` so it's able to retrieve the records.

Comment: @BookOfZeus Is my current way of doing any wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188317/discussion-between-book-of-zeus-and-daredevil).

Answer (score 1):

When you create:

```
Fmedia fmedia = new Fmedia(fileID);
fmedia.setFstatus(2);
```

It creates the object and assign the value to the status BUT will NOT save/persist the data into the database.

You need to implictly call it to make sure the EntityManager save the data.

Since you are using:

```
<groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
<artifactId>PantonMCRE</artifactId>
<version>9.5.0</version>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

you need to do:

```
Fmedia fmedia = new Fmedia(fileID);
fmedia.setFstatus(2);
em.refresh(fmedia); // This will run the "UPDATE .... WHERE nodeid = ?"
```

or use:

```
Query createQuery(CriteriaUpdate updateQuery)
```

example:

```
CriteriaUpdate<Fmedia> updateCriteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Fmedia.class);
Root<Fmedia> root = updateCriteria.from(Fmedia.class);
updateCriteria.set(Fmedia.fstatus, 2); // make this public from the model
updateCriteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(Fmedia.nodeid), fileID)); // public instead of private
em.createQuery(updateCriteria).executeUpdate();
```